# Creating some Loaded Dice to make our board game fairer

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, random, combinatorics

Some friends and I were playing a board game and decided that the random dice rolls just weren't fair! So we came up with a scheme for making the rolls slightly more evenly distributed, and I implemented it in python. The class represents 2 six sided dice and makes the probability of a given combination coming up (there are 36 options for 2 dice) inversely proportional to the number of times it has come up previously - thereby ensuring the distribution tends to be more even than randomness allows:

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import Tuple, Counter as TCounter
import random


class LoadedDice:
    """
    Simulation of 2 Dice being rolled.
    Weights the random roll to try and tend to an even distribution
    """

    def __init__(self, sides: int = 6) -> None:
        self.sides = sides
        self.history: TCounter[int] = Counter(range(sides ** 2))

    def roll(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        result_index = self.get_weighted_random_roll_index()
        self.history[result_index] += 1
        return self.roll_value_from_index(result_index)

    def get_weighted_random_roll_index(self) -> int:
        roll_threshold = random.random()
        reciprocals_total = sum(self.reciprocals())
        running_total = 0
        for result_index, value in enumerate(self.reciprocals()):
            running_total += value / reciprocals_total
            if roll_threshold <= running_total:
                return result_index

    def roll_value_from_index(self, index: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        mod, remainder = divmod(index, self.sides)
        roll_1 = mod + 1
        roll_2 = remainder + 1
        return roll_1, roll_2

    def reciprocals(self):
        for v in self.history.values():
            yield 1 / v

    @property
    def roll_history(self) -> TCounter[Tuple[int, int]]:
        result: TCounter[Tuple[int, int]] = Counter()
        for roll_index, count in self.history.items():
            result[self.roll_value_from_index(roll_index)] += count
        return result

    @property
    def result_history(self) -> TCounter[int]:
        result: TCounter[int] = Counter()
        for roll_index, count in self.history.items():
            result[sum(self.roll_value_from_index(roll_index))] += count
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.roll_history)
```

... which can be used like this:

```
especially_fair_dice = LoadedDice(6)  # simulate 2 6-sided dice
especially_fair_dice.roll()  # returns the dice values results like (1,5)
```

#### Feedback

I'd like some review on types, as I've never done them before, efficiency of my algorithm; I feel like it's a bit overly complicated, anything I've missed about pseudo-random numbers that make my approach undesirable etc.

#### Results

I plotted some of the results, for 100 rolls, the loaded die approach tends to perform better than random at keeping to the expected distribution, while still *feeling* random (that's the goal, interpret it as you wish, I don't know how to quantify it either:)
[image: comparison of rolls]

Comment: Though it doesn't affect my comment on the code or implementation, the whole premise of this problem is classically fallacious; read about the gambler's fallacy here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy

Comment: What is your intent with `1 / v ** 0`? You realize this will always evaluate to 1?

Comment: @Reinderien Oops, sorry good catch, that was me messing with the exponent (the higher the exponent, the more strongly it tends to the expectede). Edited out

Comment: I should add that this is for short games with ~50 dice rolls, over a long game the random approach does of course tend towards expected, as should the loaded die (just the loaded die tends to expected faster)

Comment: You *do* know that dice have no memory, yes?

Answer (score 3):

### Performance

If you intend on using this for (e.g.) large-scale Monte-Carlo simulation, consider moving to vectorized Numpy rather than base Python.

### Direct generators

There's no need for `yield` here:

```
    for v in self.history.values():
        yield 1 / v
```

Instead,

```
return (1/v for v in self.history.values())
```

### Counter initialization

`roll_history` can be reduced, I think, to

```
return Counter(
    (
        sum(self.roll_value_from_index(roll_index)),
        count,
    )
    for roll_index, count in self.history.items()
)
```

In other words, `Counter` accepts an iterable of key-count tuples. If the above generator expression seems unwieldy to you, write a separate method to yield roll-count pairs:

```
    for roll_index, count in self.history.items():
        roll_1, roll_2 = self.roll_value_from_index(roll_index)
        yield roll_1 + roll_2, count
```

Comment: What's the advantage of the "Direct generators" and how are they "direct"? One might as well say "There's no need for `return` here", arguing for the opposite.

Comment: @superbrain Direct in the sense that you don't need to split out a `for`-loop, and the method itself will not be a generator; it will simply return a generator object.

Comment: Well you have a `for` clause instead. What's the advantage?

Comment: Concision, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

By using the `weights` or `cum_weights` keyword argument, `random.choices()` can make a weighted selection from a population of objects.  `get_weighted_random_roll_index` could be replace with:

```
def get_weighted_random_roll_index(self):
    choices = random.choices(range(self.sides**2), weights=self.reciprocals())
    return choices[0]
```

`random.choices()` returns a list, which defaults to just 1 element.  I use `return choices[0]` because it's easy to overlook a `[0]` at the end of the previous line.